# IEnumerable<IGrouping> to IEnumerable<List>

Tags: c#, list, linq, igrouping

So I have this:

`IEnumerable<IGrouping<UInt64, MyObject>> groupedObjects = myObjectsResults.GroupBy(x => x.Id);`

The question is, how do I turn this result into an `IEnumerable<List<MyObject>>`?

This is as far as I could take it:

`IEnumerable<List<MyObject>> groupedObjects = (myObjectsResults.GroupBy(x => x.Id).SelectMany(group => group).ToList());`

which is obviously incorrect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<List<MyObject>> groupedObjects = myObjectsResults.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                                            .Select(group => group.ToList())
                                            .ToList();
```

Comment: I have the same problem but my collection is too big (Millions of elements) so I cannot call .ToList, what do you suggest please ?!

Comment: @red2nb Just use `myObjectsResults.GroupBy(x => x.Id)`, Later you can iterate on it using foreach loop.(*In fact, nested two foreach loops*)

Answer (score 6):

I think the solution is even simpler.

IGrouping IS an IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>.

Below is the signature:

```
#region Assembly System.Core.dll, v4.0.0.0
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll
#endregion

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace System.Linq
{
  // Summary:
  //     Represents a collection of objects that have a common key.
  //
  // Type parameters:
  //   TKey:
  //     The type of the key of the System.Linq.IGrouping<TKey,TElement>.This type
  //     parameter is covariant. That is, you can use either the type you specified
  //     or any type that is more derived. For more information about covariance and
  //     contravariance, see Covariance and Contravariance in Generics.
  //
  //   TElement:
  //     The type of the values in the System.Linq.IGrouping<TKey,TElement>.
  public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable
  {
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the key of the System.Linq.IGrouping<TKey,TElement>.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The key of the System.Linq.IGrouping<TKey,TElement>.
    TKey Key { get; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Comfortable Solution is to use a dictionary:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<UInt64, MyObject>> groupedObjects = myObjectsResults.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
Dictionary<UInt64, List<MyObject>> objectGroups = groupedObjects.ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```